# iCal recurrence rule misbehaving

Tags: google-calendar, icalendar

I have a long list of events that recurs every day, Monday through Saturday. I generated the following ics file: https://pastebin.com/j4yjbXFb

However, when I import this into Google Calendar (or any other calendar app), mysteriously some of the events jump to Sunday! This seems to happen with only events after 8pm on Saturday. I have examined the ics file in a text editor and the event timezone is the same as my timezone, and the RRULE is `RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA;WKST=SU` as expected. Changing the WKST to MO doesn't do anything.

What could possibly be going on here?